# Create path with minimum curvature for Ackerman drive

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, inverse-kinematics, path-planning

I'm trying to create a trajectory between two given poses for an Ackerman drive.
The poses are defined as follows:

- Current Pose

  - position $(x_0, y_0)$
  - rotation on z-axis $\theta_0$
- Final Pose

  - position $(x_f, y_f)$
  - rotation on z-axis $\theta_f$

The trajectory has to be 2 times differentiable with minimum curvature and needs a smooth transition to it's predecessor trajectory *(the steering change between two trajectories can't be instant)*.

I always stumble upon parts of the solution but am struggling to put everything together. Some people suggest using bezier curves or [cubic polynomials](http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/~alonzo/pubs/papers/fsr2001.pdf) but I couldn't find a concrete example *(something like: given current pose $[(0,0),0]$ and final pose $[(1,1),\frac{\pi}{2}]$ you can calculate the trajectory like this ...)*.

So my questions are:

1. Is [that paper](http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/~alonzo/pubs/papers/fsr2001.pdf) actually solving my problem?
2. Are there any useful tutorials/implementations/examples out there that are a bit more explanatory?

Comment: I too would like to know the solution to this problem

Comment: The paper seems to set out a solution, but it is beyond my math skill set to implement it as code. It also points to some unsolved problems around singularities, that is where there are multiple solutions.

Comment: I found another [approach](https://www.mathworks.com/help/driving/ref/lateralcontrollerstanley.html) to this problem. Matlab seems to have the exact functionality i asked for. (Still figuring out how to implement this on my own)

Comment: I found this paper with i think could be be adapted to do this [link](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/irc/2017/6724/00/07926545.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjY4Zae6t7eAhXMpY8KHeC0BDsQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw0UMPTEiT0sIhSGbmBQe8Ez)`link`